# python instance variables as optional arguments

Tags: python, function, class

In python, is there a way I can use instance variables as optional arguments in a class method? ie:

```
def function(self, arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=self.instance_var):
    # do stuff....
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
def foo(self, blah=None):
    if blah is None: # faster than blah == None - thanks to kcwu
        blah = self.instance_var
```

Comment: use "is" to compare None is better (and faster)

Comment: @kcwu thanks for the suggestion. I knew they were different, but I did a benchmark and found a large performance difference.

Comment: @kcwu hmm this is very interesting, using "is" to compare strings also shows it is 50% faster. However, this does not work with integers.

Comment: Don't compare string with "is" except you really want to compare the reference instead of value.

Comment: @kcwu but strings are unique, therefore when you do something like "a"+"s"+"d"+"f" is "asdf" then it is true.

Comment: @Unknown - no not always.  Python interns some strings depending on how they are created etc, but not all.  Try ('%s%s' %('x','y')) is ('%s%s' % ('x','y')) instead, or reading two identical strings from a file.

Comment: @Brian hmm ok, I've never seen anything about that even though it runs counter to all the documentation I have read.

Comment: @Unknown: You may be confusing strings being unique with them being immutable.  This means that they can't be changed, so it's a valid optimisation for the same strings to be represented by the same object, but you can't rely on it.  It's true only for strings which are interned.  Python automatically does this for short strings that might be an identifier, as this will improve performance for dict and variable lookups etc.  Checking every string on creation for duplicates is expensive though, so it's not done for all strings (since there's no gain if it's never compared).

Comment: You can also use other constants as sentinels like `False`, `True`, `NotImplemented`.

Comment: Is `if not blah` as fast as `if blah is None`?

Answer (score 5):

All the responses suggesting `None` are correct; if you want to make sure a caller can pass None as a regular argument, use a special `sentinel` and test with `is`:

```
class Foo(object):
  __default = object()
  def foo(self, blah=Foo.__default):
    if blah is Foo.__default: blah = self.instavar
```

Each call to `object()` makes a unique object, such that `is` will never succeed between it and any other value.  The two underscores in `__default` mean "strongly private", meaning that callers know they shouldn't try to mess with it (and would need quite some work to do so, explicitly imitating the name mangling that the compiler is doing).

The reason you can't just use the code you posted, btw, is that default values evaluate when the `def` statement evaluates, not later at call time; and at the time `def` evaluates, there is as yet no `self` from which to take the instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

no, because the instance doesn't exist when class function definition time

You have to rewrite as following

```
def function(self, arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=None):
    if arg3 is None:
        arg3 = self.instance_var
```

This is slightly different to original one: you cannot pass arg3 with None value if you really want.

Alternative solution:

```
def function(self, arg1=val1, arg2=val2, **argd):
    arg3 = argd.get('arg3', self.instance_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(self, blah=None):
    blah = blah if not blah is None else self.instance_var
```

This works with python 2.5 and forwards and handles the cases where blah is empty strings, lists and so on.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way of doing this would be:

```
def foo(self, blah=None):
    blah = blah or self.instance_var
```

This shorter version looks better, specially when there is more than one optional argument.

**Use with care. See the comments below...**

Comment: or False or an empty array… short: don't do it

Comment: as other commenters point out, this isn't really Pythonic, since it has unexpected effects.

Comment: You are all right about this. I still think it is helpful,for instance, with strings.